# What is the probability that we select the three cards in sorted (increasing) order?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we shuffle a deck of 10 cards, each bearing a distinct number from 1 to 10, to mix the cards thoroughly. We then remove three cards, one at a time, from the deck. What is the probability that we select the three cards in sorted (increasing) order?

The answer should be $\frac{\binom{10}{3}}{^{10}P_3}=\frac16$ right?

Comment: Certainly looks like you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes.

Since for every 3 cards in the deck, there is only one order of it out of six that is sorted (increasing). Therefore the probability should be 1/6

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).